# Not able to launch any application using a custom shortcut in KDE plasma

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, kde-plasma-5

This is my first question on this website.
I am using arch linux. I recently changed from Gnome desktop environment to KDE Plasma. However, I am not able to launch any application (for eg. Konsole) by adding a custom shortcut(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> because it's not already present there).

So how to figure it out?

**System specification:**

- Kernel: 5.7.9-arch1-1
- KDE Plasma version: 5.19.3